# With gnuplot, how do I iterate over ARG1, ARG2, ARGN?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using a gnuplot script to plot some data by calling it like so:

```
gnuplot -p -c script.plt first.dat
```

script.plt looks like this:

```
set grid
set yrange [0:1000]
set xrange [-1:6]
set xtic 1 rotate 90
plot ARG1 using (column(0)):2:3:4:xtic(1) with yerrorbars
```

I want to pass in more data and have them all plotted on the same figure:

```
gnuplot -p -c script.plt first.dat second.dat
```

Which I can achieve with:

```
set grid
set yrange [0:1000]
set xrange [-1:6]
set xtic 1 rotate 90
plot ARG1 using (column(0)):2:3:4:xtic(1) with yerrorbars, \
    ARG2 using (column(0)):2:3:4:xtic(1) with yerrorbars
```

But how do I pass in an arbitrary amount of data to plot?

```
gnuplot -p -c script.plt first.dat second.dat third.dat
gnuplot -p -c script.plt first.dat second.dat third.dat fourth.dat ...
```

I know it's possible to iterate using plot, but is it possible to iterate over ARGS? Something like:

```
plot for [arg in ARGS] arg using (column(0)):2:3:4:xtic(1) with yerrorbars
```

http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/iteration/

Answer (score 4):

Gnuplot supports only upto 10 `ARG` variables, i.e., `ARG0, ..., ARG9` (even though the `ARGC` variable is not limited in this way). As a workaround, you could pass all files as a white-space delimited string (assuming that your file names do not contain white-space characters) as the first argument

```
gnuplot -c script.plt "file1.dat file2.dat"
```

and then "parse" it in Gnuplot:

```
plot for [i=1:words(ARG1)] word(ARG1, i) ...
```

EDIT:

alternatively, one might aggregate all arguments into an array (assuming a recent version of Gnuplot) and then use this array in the `plot` statement:

```
N = (9 < ARGC)?9:ARGC
array ARGV[N]

do for [i=1:N] {
  eval sprintf("ARGV[%d] = ARG%d", i, i);
}

print "found ", |ARGV|, " arguments"

plot for [i=1:|ARGV|] ARGV[i] ...
```